# Remove subview created for activityIndicator with swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

i have created an activity window function which takes 3 inputs,

- msg:String - the message which should show in the activity window
- indicator:Bool - if the activity window should show or not
- view:UIView - the uiview which should get the frame sizes etc from the View Controller which its called on

everything works fine, except the part where subview needs to be removed.if the same function is run on the main view controller. it works fine. just when i moved it to NSObject, it does not. please help

```
class UIDesignFunction: NSObject {

func progressBarDisplayer(msg:String, indicator:Bool, view:UIView) {

    var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    var strLabel = UILabel()
    var msgFrame = UIView()

    if indicator{

        //println(msg)
        strLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50))
        strLabel.text = msg
        strLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        msgFrame = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: view.frame.midX - 90, y: view.frame.midY - 25 , width: 180, height: 50))
        msgFrame.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        msgFrame.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.7)

        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.White)
        activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        msgFrame.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
        msgFrame.addSubview(strLabel)
        view.addSubview(msgFrame)
    }else{
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
        msgFrame.removeFromSuperview()
    }

}
```

Comment: the mgFrame keeps showing and does not go off

Comment: willRemoveSubview did not work :( how do you use removeFromSuperviewWithoutNeedingDisplay

Comment: @MugunthanBalakrishnan Do I understand it correctly that you call that function once with `indicator = true` to display the activity indicator and then again with `indicator = false` to remove the activity indicator?

Comment: @ hennes yes thats correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the variables out of the function like below

```
class UIDesignFunction: NSObject {

var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
var strLabel = UILabel()
var msgFrame = UIView()

func progressBarDisplayer(msg:String, indicator:Bool, view:UIView) {

if indicator{

    //println(msg)
    strLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50))
    strLabel.text = msg
    strLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    msgFrame = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: view.frame.midX - 90, y: view.frame.midY - 25 , width: 180, height: 50))
    msgFrame.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    msgFrame.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.7)

    activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.White)
    activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    msgFrame.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
    msgFrame.addSubview(strLabel)
    view.addSubview(msgFrame)
}else{
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
    msgFrame.removeFromSuperview()
}

}
```